# Empty the input after javascript event click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I too tried to solve this problem but I think there have a special solution for that, I have an add button . when I click on this button a form appears in a modal with a save button and an input. the problem is when I click on this button to save for the first time it's okay , but when I click for the second time it executes twice, and when I click the 3rd time it executes 3 times....

My script

```
$table.on('click', 'button#add', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');

    jQuery('#add_div').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
    var var1 = document.getElementById("ex_:"+id).innerHTML;
    $(".modal-body #var1").val( var1 );

    $( "#btnSubmitModal" ).click(function() {
      var var1 = document.getElementById("ex_:"+id).innerHTML;
      var var2 = document.getElementById("fin:"+id).innerHTML;
      var var3 = $( "#var2" ).val();
      var var4 = parseInt(var3) + 1;
      var var5 = var2;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "id=" + id + "&var3=" + var3 + "&var4=" + var4 + "&var5=" + var5,
            success: function(response){
                var row = document.getElementById(id);
                $(insertRow(response,var4,var5)).insertAfter($(row).closest('tr'));
                document.getElementById("fin:"+id).innerHTML = var3;
                document.getElementById("debut:"+response).innerHTML = var4;
                document.getElementById("fin:"+response).innerHTML = var5;
            }
        });        
    });
});
```

i add this to empty the input but it don't work

```
 document.getElementById("var2").value = "";
```

Comment: if you use jQuery ... do all with jquery. It gives to you more advantages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I resolve it by replacing this line :

```
$( "#btnSubmitModal" ).click(function() {
```

By this :

```
$( "#btnSubmitModal" ).one('click',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem i solve it below ..

i stored instance of modal into variable and add listeners on it.
Now i call same one instance of modal and change only content what i want.

```
var modal = $('#myModal');

    // listeners
    $('.list-group li').click(function() {
        modal.modal('show');
        modal.find('#myModalLabel').text(self.data('office'));
        modal.find('#office').val(self.data('office'));
        modal.find('select[name=rights] :nth-child(1)').prop('selected', true);
    });

    modal.on('click', '.btn-primary', function () {
        console.log('modal ok and hidden');
        modal.modal('hide');
    });
```

and it worked properly

i give to you full source

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
.box { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: gray; }
.added { color: red; }
</style>

<div id="offices" style="width: 30%;">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" data-office="office1">office 1 <span class="pull-right"></span></li>
      <li class="list-group-item" data-office="office2">office 2 <span class="pull-right"></span></li>
      <li class="list-group-item" data-office="office3">office 3 <span class="pull-right"></span></li>
      <li class="list-group-item" data-office="office4">office 4 <span class="pull-right"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">label</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                role <select name="rights"><option value="admin">admin</option><option value="user">user</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" id="office" value=""> 
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var modal = $('#myModal');

// listeners
$('.list-group li').click(function() {
    modal.modal('show');
    modal.find('#myModalLabel').text(self.data('office'));
    modal.find('#office').val(self.data('office'));
    modal.find('select[name=rights] :nth-child(1)').prop('selected', true);
});

modal.on('click', '.btn-primary', function () {
    console.log('modal ok and hidden');
    modal.modal('hide');
});


});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way you use your modal it's not the same that i use it. I can't found the solution in your code

Comment: sorry mybe i am misunderstanding but you have problem if you click, your code runing multiple times. I had same problem with modal. Modal instance cause this issue. Try make one instance and add listeners on same instance. It will solve your problem with multiply running code

Comment: i show full source ... you can save it with libraries and try it.

Comment: I integrate your code in my project but it don't work. I click on office1 and select user. And when i click on office2 the modal show a select box with user as selected item.

Comment: yes, my logic it not here. But in listeners you can set it up your modal content (data). I clear the form data on submit. But look into console if you click on offices and click submit if run the code multiplies?